# How can I set up light on cycles to accurately pass through multiple panels of glass?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, lighting, glass

Im trying to make a small cafe scene with a patisserie display in it. It takes place at night and one of the aspects I wanted to explore was to have it as bright fluorescent spot on the final render. As so I wanted to setup a fluorescent lamp inside it, not unlike some in the real world.

The inside is composed of 3 glass panels, and a metallic reflective bottom panel. I inittialy went with an emission material for the lamp. But no matter how strong I set up the nodes, light just won't reach the bottom of the display, leaving the whole thing dark. I then tried to use an area lamp in a similar position, and still no effect. The light just dies before it can reach the whole display.

[image]

Here are the current light settings I'm using:

[image]

The display mesh and glass material setup:

[image]

If anyone has any insight on how to set this up I would be very thankful.

Comment: If you don't need refraction or frefractive caustics, you might want to use what's called architectural glass. It's any glass material you want, but mixed with a transparent shader by the factor 'IsShadowRay' from the light path node.
This way you can tint/darken your shadows from the transparent shader. 
If that's not what you want, make sure your total max bounces are not lower than the desired ones. You're cutting off 4 transmission bounces by clamping the total to 8.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work!